# Real-time analytics always shows 100% new

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics

Real-time Google Analytics used to show new vs. returning visitors by default but then they switched to Desktop vs. Mobile. I've now setup a custom dashboard based on #3 [found here](http://p.barker.dj/category/google-analytics). However, this shows that 100% of my visitors are new. I never see a returning visitor in real-time. (If I go to Audience > Overview I can see that I do indeed have returning visitors but the stats are not in real-time).

How do I correctly get the number of new vs. returning visitors in real-time?

Answer (score 2):

This custom dashboard does not show new versus returning visitors, but new AND returning visitors.

If you want to only see new visitors, you can program it yourself using the Google Analytics Real Time Reporting API, see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/user

I am not aware of another possibility (w/o programming)

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I'm asking why the data is wrong.

Comment: The custom dashboard shows new AND returning. It is not capable of splitting. Therefore, the sum always equal 100%. The data is not wrong.

Comment: That's not the issue. Why are 100% of my visitors new and 0% are returning (when I KNOW people are returning)?

Comment: Always leave one 'view' that is unfiltered: No filtering out IPs; no adjustments to users; no custom parameters.

That way when things go haywire (as they always will, analytics is complex and frequently changes) you can quantify, compare, and diagnose the problem.

Comment: I've tried it with unfiltered and filtered data. No difference.

Comment: So this started happening to both the iOS and Android mobile apps as soon as I switched to the new analytics.js -- not sure if this info helps, but I have found no solution to it yet. Very annoying..!